# Using Schema with `the_excerpt`

Tags: functions, excerpt, html5, html

I'm currently developing a WordPress site and want to use Schema, I have been some what successful so far but have now hit a stone wall. I want to use: `itemprop="description"` to the `<p>`the_exerpt`</p>`.

Since I was able to the itemprop easily to `the_post_thumbnail` using:

`<?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail',array('itemprop'=>'image')); ?>`

I assumed this would be a easy task, but turns out its slightly more complex for the exerpt tag.

I have tried the following with no success:

1. `<?php the_excerpt('excerpt',array('itemprop'=>'description')); ?>`
2. `<?php the_excerpt('the_excerpt',array('itemprop'=>'description')); ?>`

Currently my excerpt in `functions.php` looks like:

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '...<a class="small button secondary" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '" itemprop="url">Continue Reading</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution but this works fine:

```
<?php remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop'); ?>
```